# How to add short keys in one note other than 0 to 9

Tags: microsoft-onenote

[can we create short keys for tags other than 0 to 9 ? How?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bd9YO.png)

Answer (score 0):

It [looks like only 0-9](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Keyboard-shortcuts-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-44b8b3f4-c274-4bcc-a089-e80fdcc87950) can be used as regular tag shortcuts, however, a user at [microsoft answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_onenote-mso_other/creating-tag-shortcuts/1672551a-b596-46df-ba76-4b7ae0bcc299), suggests to use [autohotkey](https://autohotkey.com/) or similar to map the keystroke combination to access your tag (eg: `<Alt>-H, T, DownArrow x10`) to an autohotkey shortcut.